# Align The text as center in menu bar

Tags: html, css

I'm facing this issue in a menu bar.

I need to align the text with the center of the icon.

[image]

**Code:**

```
<table id="cssTable">
    <thead>
         <tr>
             <th>
                <i style=" text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;" class="icon s20 {{node.icon}}" ng-if="node.icon"></i>
             </th>
         </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
         <tr>
             <td>
                  <span style=" text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;" class="title" translate="{{node.translate}}" flex>{{node.title}}</span>
             </td>
         </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But it's not working. How  do I use css to style the center the text.

Comment: We don't know what your current CSS looks like (apart from the inline-rules within your markup). How about you provide a [mcve]? In other words, add the relevant CSS and make that a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: can't be sure without seeing your css, but `text-align: center` should work. Also, do not use inline js/css - it's bad practice that leads to hard-to-maintain code, move to external css files

Comment: Apart from the text-align issue at hand, may I ask why you are using a `table` for your menu? And also why you are using inline-styles instead of an external stylesheet or styles in the `head` of your page?

Answer (score 2):

**To fix the issue at hand**, remove the `text-align: center` from the `span` and instead add it to the parent elements, `th` and `td`.

However, your code is showing some other issues that I'd like to point out.

**Why the `table`?**

You are using a `table` for your menu. Unless you have a very specific, pressing reason to do so, you should not do this. The reason is that HTML is all about semantics, and it is not very semantic to make a menu a table - it simply isn't tabular data. The common practice is to use an unordered list (`ul`) instead.

**Why the inline-styles?**

There are three ways to apply CSS:

- External stylesheet using [`<link>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link)
- [`<style></style>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style) section within your `<head>`
- Inline-styles (that's what you are using)

Now, inline-styles will override rules  from external stylesheets or the `style` element. They also violate the idea of separating content and presentation. They are therefore considered bad practice, unless you have a specific reason to use them.

**Putting it all together**

I therefore suggest the following:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 108px;
}

li {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #2d323e;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center 20%;
}

li.customers,
li.user {
  background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/20x20);
}

li a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 94px;
  padding-top: 60%;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 9pt;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="customers"><a href="#1">Customers</a></li>
  <li class="user"><a href="#2">User</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: nice full answer :)

Answer (score 1):

it's because you're adding `text-align` to the span property, and I can understand why you would try to add it to the span. But `text-align` is best used on the parent element, to essentially align the children elements.

You would do something like this (not meant to be anything like your code, just an example of how-to-use):

html:

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <img src="img1.png" class="img" />
    <p>My Text</p>
</div>
```

css:

```
#myDiv {text-align: center;}
```

not whenever a div with an id of `myDiv` is loaded it will center-align all child elements inside the div.

In your case, you need to add it to the table `<td>`/`<th>` that holds the text you wish to align. E.g.

`td, th {text-align: center}`

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, using flexbox and absolute positioning of the icon.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 5em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1.5em;
  min-width: 5em;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: .1em;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

li:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1em;
  top: 0.3em;
  left: calc(50% - .5em);
}

.customers:before {
  content: "\f0c0";
}

.user:before {
  content: "\f2c0";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul>
  <li class="customers">Customers</li>
  <li class="user">User</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add `text-align:center` to the `th` and `td`

```
<th style="text-align: center;"></th>
<td style="text-align: center;"></td>
```

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo

Comment: No worries, that's why I commented. I would still refrain from using inline-styles; after all, we are here to deliver quality answers and not to teach techniques that are better avoided.